# Refernce ID's on a query which fetch assoc and result do not work on

Tags: php, sql, reference, echo

‎

```
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT `user_name` FROM `users` WHERE `id` LIKE '$id'"); 

echo $query1;

if (mysql_num_rows($query1) == 0)
    die ("User not found");
else {
    $username = mysql_result($query1);
    echo $username ;
}
```

Could someone tell me why i'd keep getting resource **ID**'s and then 'array' echoed out?! I've tried fetch assoc and MySQL fetch and still nothing unfortunately :( I've read through the manual and still no joy!

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to display the value in the "user_name" column? If so, you need a loop that looks like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
    $username = $row['user_name'];
    echo "user_name = " . $username;
}
```

Place it inside your "else" block, replacing what's currently inside it. The way you did it, your $username variable is getting the Result Set object, not the data inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql_result, but you have to specify the row number as a second parameter

```
mysql_result($query1, 0);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php

Or you can do...

```
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT `user_name` FROM `users` WHERE `id` LIKE '$id'"); 



if (mysql_num_rows($query1)==0){
    die ("User not found");
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query1)){
echo $row['user_name'];
}
```

By the way you do not have to use LIKE, rather = would be good.